# Calling ADLS Data in python script inside VS Code

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-data-lake

I already installed the ADL extension in VS code and now i am writing a Python script, where i need to read a csv file present in Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS Gen1). 
For local file the following code is working:

```
df = pd.read_csv(Path('C:\\Users\\Documents\\breslow.csv')) 
print (df)
```

How i can read data from ADLS?
Even after successful installation and connection(with my Azure account) of ADL extension do i still need to go for creating a scope and secret and all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to write a sample code to read data from a csv file in Azure Data Lake to a dataframe in pandas.

Here is my sample code as below.

```
from azure.datalake.store import core, lib, multithread
import pandas as pd

tenant_id = '<your Azure AD tenant id>'
username = '<your username in AAD>'
password = '<your password>'
store_name = '<your ADL name>'
token = lib.auth(tenant_id, username, password)
# Or you can register an app to get client_id and client_secret to get token
# If you want to apply this code in your application, I recommended to do the authentication by client
# client_id = '<client id of your app registered in Azure AD, like xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx'
# client_secret = '<your client secret>'
# token = lib.auth(tenant_id, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)

adl = core.AzureDLFileSystem(token, store_name=store_name)
f = adl.open('<your csv file path, such as data/test.csv in my ADL>')
df = pd.read_csv(f)
```

Note: If you were using `client_id` & `client_secret` for authentication, you must add the necessary access permission for the app which has `Reader` role at least in Azure AD, as the figures below. For more information about accessing security, please see the offical document [`Security in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-security-overview). Meanwhile, about how to register an app in Azure AD, you can refer to my answer for the other SO thread [How to get an AzureRateCard with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54760786/how-to-get-an-azureratecard-with-java/54784589#54784589).

[image]

[image]

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi @Peter_Pan, first of all thank you so much for your detailed reply. Actually when i use code mentioned by you without using client_id and client secret, Ie. only this part 
tenant_id = '<your Azure AD tenant id>'
username = '<your username in AAD>'
password = '<your password>'
store_name = '<your ADL name>'
token = lib.auth(tenant_id, username, password)
i am getting this error : Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060]
currently i don't have access to AAD that's why i choosed this way :-(

Comment: @LavMehta Fine, it's up to your real scenario. Whatever you used, to make it works fine is important first. If my answer helps, could you mark it as answer?

Comment: Actually i am getting an error : Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060]  when i execute this line to be specific: token = lib.auth(tenant_id, username, password). 
and i tried marking your answer as useful but it shows : thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. Sorry i think i need more reputation :-))

Comment: Using Client Id and Client Secret it was much easier and error free to solve the problem. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for reading csv file from ADLS.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Mar 20 11:37:19 2019

@author: Mohit Verma
"""

from azure.datalake.store import core, lib, multithread
token = lib.auth(tenant_id, username, password)
adl = core.AzureDLFileSystem(token, store_name=store_name)

# typical operations
adl.ls('')
adl.ls('tmp/', detail=True)
adl.ls('tmp/', detail=True, invalidate_cache=True)
adl.cat('littlefile')
adl.head('gdelt20150827.csv')

# file-like object
with adl.open('gdelt20150827.csv', blocksize=2**20) as f:
    print(f.readline())
    print(f.readline())
    print(f.readline())
    # could have passed f to any function requiring a file object:
    # pandas.read_csv(f)

with adl.open('anewfile', 'wb') as f:
    # data is written on flush/close, or when buffer is bigger than
    # blocksize
    f.write(b'important data')

adl.du('anewfile')

# recursively download the whole directory tree with 5 threads and
# 16MB chunks
multithread.ADLDownloader(adl, "", 'my_temp_dir', 5, 2**24)
```

Please try this code and see if it helps.For other samples related to Azure Data Lake please refer to below github repo.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-python/tree/master/azure

Also if you want to understand different type of authentication in ADLS, please check the below code base.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/data-lake-analytics-python-auth-options/blob/master/sample.py

Comment: Hi @Mohit Verma, thanks for the detailed code, All the typical operations and other commands would be helpful only after i have successful access. After 3rd line of your code i am getting some proxy error "Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] ". could you help me with that?.

Comment: By looking at the error code, seems a proxy related issue.

Comment: This basically means that no response (either positive or negative) was received from the remote host when the TCP connection attempt took place.
One reason this may happen is because a firewall is blocking the response from the server.

Another reason is that the host name is incorrect.

This could also mean there is a (temporary) problem with the server (or some router along the way). You can try a traceroute to determine whether or not this is true.

Comment: Thanks Mohit your code for typical operations was very helpful. I used the method mentioned above by doing App registration and it worked well. Thanks for your input!